# Regex match words that are not part of a larger word

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to use Regex in C# to look for a list of keywords in a bunch of text. However I want to be very specific about what the "surrounding" text can be for something to count as a keyword.

So for example, the keyword "hello" should be found in (hello), hello., hello< but not in hellothere.

My main problem is that I don't REQUIRE the separators, if the keyword is the first word or the last word it's okay. I guess another way to look at it is that the beginning-of-the-file and the end-of-the-file should be acceptable separators.

I'm new to Regex so I was hoping someone could help me get the pattern right. So far I have:

```
[ <(.]+?keyword[<(.]+?
```

where <, (, . are some example separators and keyword is of course the keyword I am looking for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
(^$|[ <(.])+?keyword($|[<(.]+?)
```

The `^` and `$` chars symbolise the start and end of the input text, respectively. (If you specify the `Multiline` option, it matches to the start/end of the line rather than text, but you would seem to want the `Singleline` option.)

Comment: Singleline lets the '.' (dot) metacharacter match line-separator characters (\r and \n); it would have no effect on this regex, since the only dots are in character classes, where they would just match dots anyway.

Comment: @Alan: My point was only that Singleline/Multiline option changes the meaning of `^` and `$`, not `.` The question states that the OP specifically wants to detect `.` as a seperator.

Comment: It sounds like you're thinking of Singleline and Multiline as the opposing states of a single toggle setting.  The names seems to imply as much, but in fact they're completely independent:  Singleline changes the meaning of '.' and Multiline changes the meaning of '^' and '$'. "Singleline" always was an unfortunate name; some flavors call it DOTALL mode, which is much more descriptive.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) anchor:

```
\bkeyword\b
```

which would find your keyword only when not part of a larger word.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look into the `word boundary` (\b) to avoid matching keywords that appear as a part of another word (as in your hellothere example).

You can also add matching at beginning of line (^) and end of line ($) to control the position where keywords may appear.